# set variable with conditions in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-polymer, flutter-animation

I have `MyDateTime` class and it has a variable `hour`. I need to set this variable with some condition when I create an object. For example, I have this object: 

`MyDateTime dt = MyDateTime(2020, 2, 3, 3, 2);`

now I need to increment the `hour` i.e. `dt.hour++;`

my question how I can change the `hour` of the object without adding new functions, at the same time i need to increment the `hour` with condition

```dart
class MyDateTime {
  int year;
  int month;
  int day;
  int hour;
  int minute;
  int second;

  MyDateTime({this.year, this.month, this.day ,this.hour=0, this.minute=0, this.second=0});
  // this is the condition
  set addHour(int h){
    if(this.hour == 23) this.hour = 0;
    else if(this.hour == 0) this.hour = 1;
    else this.hour++;
  }



}
```

I don't want to have function (ex: `addHour`)

Is there way to do it?

Comment: You want to have a functionality in your class without having a function?

Comment: yes if possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom setter for this purpose:

```dart
class MyDateTime {
  int year;
  int month;
  int day;
  int _hour;
  int minute;
  int second;

  MyDateTime({this.year, this.month, this.day, int hour=0, this.minute=0, this.second=0}) : _hour = hour;


  // this is the condition
  set hour(int h) => _hour = h % 24;

  // We need to define a custom getter as well.
  int get hour => _hour;
}
```

Then you can do the following:

```dart
main() {
  final dt = MyDateTime();
  print(dt.hour); // 0
  print(++dt.hour); // 1
  dt.hour += 2;
  print(dt.hour); // 3 
}
```

Comment: it give this error ``` Named optional parameters can't start with an underscore ```

Comment: Ah shoot, that's right. I've edited the answer to fix the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. **For auto increment:**

    Look into `Timer` which will allow you to automatically increment `hour` after a defined `Duration`

   https://fluttermaster.com/tips-to-use-timer-in-dart-and-flutter/
2. **For adding conditions to your increment:**

   If you don't want to keep calling a function in order to increment your `hour` variable, you will have to add some sort of listener to the `hour` variable, have a look at the following package:

   **property_change_notifier :** https://pub.dev/packages/property_change_notifier

   Adding a listener to `hour` will help you define a function like your `addHour()` function which will automatically be called when the value of `hour` is changed.

   OR You could add the conditions for increment within the `Timer` itself.